# LazyColumn and mutable list - how to update?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Jetpack Compose and I've spent some hours to find how to make a LazyColumn update what I update my list. I've read that it needs to be a immutable list to update LazyColumn, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The code looks like:

```
@Composable
fun CreateList() {
    var myList : List<DailyItem> by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf())}
    
    myList = getDailyItemList() // Returns a List<DailyItem> with latest values and uses mutable list internally
    
    // Function to refresh the list
    val onUpdateClick = {
        // Do something that updates the list
        ...
        // Get the updated list to trigger a recompose
        myList = getDailyItemList()
    }
    // Create the lazy column
    ...
}
```

I have tried several things and either is the list never updated when tapping the update button or only the first item is updated but not the rest of the items in the list. I looked in the documentation and there it says this, but I don't understand it:

> Instead of using non-observable mutable objects, we recommend you use
> an observable data holder such as State<List> and the immutable
> listOf().

How to update the list so the LazyColumn is updated?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `SnapshotStateList`, the list is mutable. Any modification (add, remove, clear, ...) to the list will trigger an update in `LazyColumn`.

Similar to `mutableListOf()` (for `MutableList`) there is `mutableStateListOf()` to create a `SnapshotStateList`.

Extention function `swapList()` just combines `clear()` and `addAll()` calls to replace old list with new list.

```
fun <T> SnapshotStateList<T>.swapList(newList: List<T>){
    clear()
    addAll(newList)
}

@Composable
fun CreateList() {
    val myList = remember { mutableStateListOf<DailyItem>() }
    
    myList.swapList(getDailyItemList()) // Returns a List<DailyItem> with latest values and uses mutable list internally

    // Function to refresh the list
    val onUpdateClick = {
        // Do something that updates the list
        ...
        // Get the updated list to trigger a recompose
        myList.swapList(getDailyItemList())
    }
    // Create the lazy column
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it didnt work for me.

my code is here :
https://pastebin.com/RfsRf8bf

Comment: @KaranAhuja You are updating content of an item, not the item itself. MutableStateList won't know if the content within an item changes. Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69718059/android-jetpack-compose-mutablestatelistof-not-doing-recomposition If you need more then please consider creating a new question for it.

Comment: @OmKumar Thanks for your comment. It is exactly what i was looking for.
I also checked the other question you mentioned.
That is exactly my question.

Thanks bro.

Answer (score 2):

See the basic idea is to get compose treat the list as state. Now that, you are able to achieve using mutableStateOf(initialValue),

Okay, the process is this,.

We create a variable, initialising it as a mutable state of something

Then we assign that variable to the lazy column. It is not necessary to assign it to the items parameter of the column, but that is our use case here. Otherwise, inside the Composable containing the lazy column, you could just type the name of the variable and even that will work since all we want, is compose to get a message that this variable is being read by the Composable.

Back to the question,

We create a variable, say `val mList: List<Int> by remember {  mutableStateOf (listOf()) }`

```
Lazycolumn{
  items(items = mList){
    Text(it)
  }
}

Button(onClick = { mList = mList + listOf(mList.size())})
```

Clicking the button adds a new number to the list, which is reflected in the LazyColumn's UI.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. Appreciate it when I'm new to the concept!

Comment: Actually this IS the correct way of doing it. Read the docs! This is straightforward. Check any official sample apps. This is the usage

Comment: How can we delete an item by index?