# LazyColumn items stay in same position after some items removed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I have LazyColumn with swipe-to-delete. When I swipe an item, it is deleted by viewModel. The problem is that if I swipe the item away, the LazyColumn doesn't update the position of other items (as shown in GIF).

[image]

Here's my code implementation:

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    val livedata = viewModel.itemsLiveData.observeAsState()
    val stateList = remember { mutableStateListOf<Data>() }

    stateList.addAll(livedata.value!!)
    SwipableLazyColumn(stateList)
}

@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun SwipableLazyColumn(
    stateList: SnapshotStateList<Data>
) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(items = stateList) { item ->
            val dismissState = rememberDismissState()
            if (dismissState.isDismissed(EndToStart) || dismissState.isDismissed(StartToEnd)) {
                viewModel.swipeToDelete(item)
            }
            SwipeToDismiss(
                state = dismissState,
                directions = setOf(StartToEnd, EndToStart),
                dismissThresholds = {
                    FractionalThreshold(0.25f)
                },
                background = {},
                dismissContent = {
                    MyData(item)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I use `SnapshotStateList` as it's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68046535/lazycolumn-and-mutable-list-how-to-update). Although I don't use `swapList` because it clears out all items

**ViewModel**:

```
    class MyViewModel @Inject internal constructor(
    private val itemRepository: ItemRepository
) : BaseViewModel(), LifecycleObserver {

    private val itemsList = mutableListOf<MyData>()

    private val _itemsLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<MyData>>()
    val itemsLiveData: LiveData<List<MyData>> = _itemsLiveData

    init {
        loadItems()
    }

    private fun loadItems() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            itemRepository.getItems().collect {
                when (it) {
                    is Result.Success -> onItemsLoaded(it.data)
                    is Result.Error -> {
                        onItemsLoaded(emptyList())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun onItemsLoaded(itemsList: List<MyData>) {
        itemsList.clear()
        itemsList.addAll(notifications)

        _itemsLiveData.value = if (itemsList.isNotEmpty()) {
            itemsList
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    fun swipeToDelete(item: MyData) {
        if (itemsList.size == 0) return
        viewModelScope.launch {
            when (
                val result =
                    itemRepository.deletelItem(item)
            ) {
                is Result.Success -> {
                    onItemDeleted(item)
                }
                is Result.Error -> {
                    showSnackBar(
                        "error"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun onItemDeleted(item: MyData) {
        itemsList.remove(item)
        _itemsLiveData.value = itemsList
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide viewmodel code?

Comment: @Jakoss added Viewmodel code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refresh your list inside viemodel(delete item) and return modified list right here

```
var tempList = itemList
ItemList.clear() 
ItemList.addAll(tempList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `key` for the `LazyColumn`'s `items`.

> By default, each item's state is keyed against the position of the
> item in the list. However, this can cause issues if the data set
> changes, since items which change position effectively lose any
> remembered state.

**Example**

```
LazyColumn {
    items(
        items = stateList,
        key = { _, listItem ->
            listItem.hashCode()
        },
    ) { item ->
        // As it is ...
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#item-keys)

Comment: while i agree he should attach key, i don't think this is the solution to the problem. I think it might be something weird in the viewmodel

Comment: @Abnimanyu I added keys , but it did not solve the problem. I also added ViewModel  to my stackOverFlow question